# The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders in Next.js Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, element-ui

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
type ButtonProps = {
  type: string,
    children: ReactNode,
    onClick: () => void
}
const ButtonWrapper: React.ComponentType<{}> = dynamic(() => import('element-react').then((res: any) => { return res.Button }), { ssr: false})

export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = (ButtonProps) => {
    return <><ButtonWrapper {...ButtonProps}></ButtonWrapper></>
}
```

I tried to implement Element-React UI to my next.js project, and I got this warning, and I want to solve it. I didn't warn when I comment this component code.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in some `useEffect`. React detected that dependency array has changed size. To fix it you need to find that `useEffect` and figure out why this is happening. Check error message to find a stacktrace to the component that causes error.
This seems like the error is inside the library component. In this case you need to check if it's misused or perhaps it's a bug in a library. Try searching github issues of the project.